# django format of url import

Tags: python, django

I am importing some views to the urls.py file, here is what I have

```
from views.home import HomeView
from views.list_player import PlayerList
from views.list_game import GameList
from views.create_player import PlayerCreate
from views.create_game import GameCreate
from views.detail_player import PlayerDetail
from views.detail_game import GameDetail
from views.update_player import PlayerUpdate
from views.update_game import GameUpdate
from views.delete_player import PlayerDelete
from views.delete_game import GameDelete
```

However, is there a way to import them like this?

```
from .views import(
    Home,
    GameList,
    PlayerList,
    PlayerDetail,
    GameDetail,
    PlayerCreate,
    GameCreate,
    PlayerUpdate,
    PlayerDelete,
    GameUpdate,
    GameDelete
    )
```

which looks much more cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements are functionally equivalent.

From http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/, the use of parentheses was approved for enclosing long lists of imports in a pythonic way, for Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text,
LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END)
```

It seems that parentheses were added for the second statement because the import list was too long.

However, you see you have varied package imports from different folders of the package. So I guess due to the intermediate folders like `home`, `list_player`, `list_game` you won't be able to do direct imports. So the best way I can see is doing this:

```
from .views import (
home,
list_player,
list_game,
create_player,
create_game,
...
)
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

it easier to import like this:

```
from <appname> import views #in urls.py
```

and inside url patterns you can use:

```
 path(<regex>, views.<viewname>) #url patterns
```